# Python3.2: Installing MySQL-python fails with error "No module named ConfigParser"

Tags: python, pip, python-3.2

I want to use SQLAlchemy with MySQL database. I've created the Engine and tried to connect but I get an error as follows.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://dbuser:pass@localhost/mydb')
Base = declarative_base(Engine)
```

That fails with the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/connectors/mysqldb.py", line 57, in dbapi
return __import__('MySQLdb')
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Searching for that I found that you have to have to install MySQLdb for python to play nice with MySQL. So trying to install it with either **pip-3.2 or easy_install-3.2** fails as below.

```
sudo pip-3.2 install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
from setup_posix import get_config
 File "setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
```

I then figure I have to install **configparser** so when I try to do so it also fails

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.2.egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.2.egg/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
import distutils.core
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 19, in <module>
from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/config.py", line 8, in <module>
from configparser import ConfigParser
 File "configparser.py", line 122
```

So, my original issue is trying to get Python to work with MySQL. But trying to resolve that I can't be able to install MySQLdb.

**EDIT**
Gone ahead as instructed by @robertklep below and installed pymsql3.

```
sudo pip-3.2 install pymysql3
```

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQLdb doesn't have Python 3 support. Try an alternative which has, like [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) (which is [supported by SQLAlchemy as well](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql)).

**EDIT**: there's also [this project](https://github.com/clelland/MySQL-for-Python-3).

Comment: Thanks for that. Wasted a whole day yesterday. I see there is pymysql3 and pymysql_sa and it states that pymysql_sa is a PyMySQL dialect for SQLAlchemy. So which should I install? Think the pymysql_sa has more advantages to pymysql3 given that am working specifically with sqlalchemy?

Comment: found out the "hardway". Tried installing pymysql_sa and it failed. Most likely coz its not compatible with Python3. So yeah, stuck with pymysql3. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using pymysql3 and I [run into problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170450/sqlalchemypymysql-error-sqlalchemy-util-queue-empty) which as pointed out there is a bug in sqlalchemy. Do you have a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/UsingMySQL

```
pip install --user https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.tar.gz
```

Then, update your settings.py to use the oracle django backend, "mysql.connector.django":

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
         ...
```

Comment: After trying this, I got "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend."