# SQLAlchemy+pymysql Error: sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-3.2

Trying to run Python3.2, SQLAlchemy0.8 and MySQL5.2 on Ubuntu using Eclispse but I keep getting the error below. Am using pymysql (pymysql3 actually) engine.

**module monitor**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:mypass@localhost/mydb')
Base = declarative_base(Engine)
Metadata = MetaData(bind=Engine)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer
Session = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
session = Session()

class Student(Base):
    __table__ = Table('student_name', Metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    autoload=True)
```

With that, when I run the module it throws the error as indicated below. What am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 757, in _do_get
return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py", line 166, in get
raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lukik/workspace/upark/src/monitor.py", line 12, in <module>
class Parking(Base):
File "/home/lukik/workspace/upark/src/monitor.py", line 15, in Parking
autoload=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 333, in __new__
table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 397, in _init
self._autoload(metadata, autoload_with, include_columns)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 425, in _autoload
self, include_columns, exclude_columns
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1604, in run_callable
with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1671, in contextual_connect
self.pool.connect(),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 272, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 425, in __init__
rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 777, in _do_get
con = self._create_connection()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 225, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 322, in __init__
exec_once(self.connection, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/event.py", line 381, in exec_once
self(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/event.py", line 398, in __call__
fn(*args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 168, in first_connect
dialect.initialize(c)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2052, in initialize
default.DefaultDialect.initialize(self, connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 172, in initialize
self._get_default_schema_name(connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2019, in _get_default_schema_name
return connection.execute('SELECT DATABASE()').scalar()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 664, in execute
params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 808, in _execute_text
statement, parameters
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 871, in _execute_context
context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 322, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 105, in execute
query = query % escaped_args
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql-connector-python` and `oursql` work fine for me under py3k.

## How to install?

```bash
$ pip install mysql-connector-python
```

## Usage

```python
Engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://<USERNAME>:<PASSWD>@<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/<DBNAME>')
```

Comment: I have the same 'sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty' error when attempting to run asynchronous DB queries using mysql-connector-python in py3k. I spawn a separate thread from the main one so that the user doesn't have to wait for a **really** long DB operation to complete, then attempt to connect to the DB in the new thread, and get this error on my production server while it works fine in development. What gives??

Comment: I think you should create another question with the details specific to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Stay on py2k or a different DB driver for the time being. This is a known SQLAlchemy bug: [2663](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2663).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the pointer. I tried MySQL-python and it failed as [shown here on SO](http://tinyurl.com/cld7qf9). I read that pymysql was python3x compatible but as you state there is a bug in sqlalchemy. Now what other driver is there to use? I tried oursql and it had bugs and someone pointed out to [LukeCarrier's Version of oursql](https://github.com/LukeCarrier/py3k-oursql) but I can't figure out how to install it. So am stuck or I need to move to py2k which as a new python programmer isn't that enticing since I just want to take off on the latest version and move from there.

Comment: There's always switching to postgresql also.  If you really want to be into Python, we like that database a lot more on this side of the fence.

Comment: by py2k do you mean python 2.x? There seems to be no such term as py2k in the documentation, only [py3k](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) which means just 3.0, not 3.x.