# Which DBDriver works for Python3x and SQLAlchemy0.8 for MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to get Python3.2 and SQLAlchemy0.8 to play nice with MySQL but I've failed miserably :-(

I tried [using Mysql-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140855/python3-2-installing-mysql-python-fails-with-error-no-module-named-configparse/15153423#15153423) but I failed as it emerged that MySQL-python is not yet compatible with python3x.

I then moved on to pymysql and it also came to a [screeching halt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140855/python3-2-installing-mysql-python-fails-with-error-no-module-named-configparse/15153423#15153423) as I was again notified that it is not compatible with python3x despite it being listed on the SQLAlchemy page as a suitable driver.

Reading through SO I got pointed out to [Luke Carrier's Oursql](https://github.com/LukeCarrier/py3k-oursql) which I have no idea -yet- of how to install since its on github and I've never used github. Am  new to python let a lone open source programming.

I've just finished a project using Postgresql and its working fine but the most popular open source db (as they claim) seems to be falling short.

So as I try and learn how to make use of github for me to try out luke carriers oursql -which I hope won't also die on me-, I just have one question. Isn't there anybody there using Python3x, SQLAlchemy and MySQL? If so, which driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into OurSQL but there was a bug during the install. With that in mind I did some research and found the following [mailing list entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/mMKAwKWSeus) which notes:

> The only drivers supported for MySQL + Py3K are OurSQL and
>   MySQL-connector/python.

With that in mind I attempted the [MySQL-connector/python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-src-unix.html) route, as it is featured on the MySQL official dev site (you will need an Oracle account to download it though). After downloading the file, I simply extracted it and ran:

```
python setup.py install
```

You'll need the MySQL client libraries installed. From there I used [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install sqlalchemy:

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

Finally I did a quick test in the Python REPL:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://myuser:mypassword@localhost/test')                                                                                                                        
>>>
```

It's important to note the `mysql+mysqlconnector` portion as that is not the default driver for sqlalchemy. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At least its worked and I can access the tables. Haven't queried inside the tables for now so I won't celebrate just yet. But its a step in the right direction. I can access my database

Comment: Ooh, and you don't need an oracle account. At the bottom of the download page you can select "No thanks, just start my download"!

Comment: I've now tested the querying with several tables and I can comfortably say that mysqlconnector from Oracle is the driver to use.