# Python error trying install mysql-connector via pip

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, mysql-connector

I'm to trying create a project in Python using Django. One of the dependencies is a connection with Mysql. I'm Using pip to import whatever I need.

My problem is the error when I run this line: `sudo pip3 install mysql-python`

The return is:

`Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-6dok9yt5/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-install-6dok9yt5/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`

The final line is: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-6dok9yt5/mysql-python/`

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3.2: Installing MySQL-python fails with error "No module named ConfigParser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140855/python3-2-installing-mysql-python-fails-with-error-no-module-named-configparse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know "mysql-python" currently does not support python3

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is supported.

Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724855/966660

Comment: Hi @user966660! Thank you for your reply! Exactly this! My problem was solved! **Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.11 protobuf-3.5.2.post1** Thank you!